# Does small number of objects have a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm going through the book JavaScript: The Definitive Guide 7th edition.

And in objects section I encountered a strange phrase that

> Remember: almost all objects have a prototype, but only a relatively small number of objects have a prototype property. It is these objects with prototype properties that define the prototypes for all the other objects.

What I find confusing is that it says first, *almost every object has a prototype* and then says *only a relatively small number of objects have a prototype property*. I find these as two contradicting statements; how come almost every object has a prototype while everyone of them doesn't get to have prototype property.

Can you explain what above statement means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can enlight you: (the sentence is not well formulated, `almost all objects have a prototype chain inheritance, but only a relatively small number of objects defines a prototype property`)

```js
function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {// prototype property on Foo
    console.log('bar');
};

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.__proto__);// object

const baz = Object.create(null);
console.log(baz.__proto__);// undefined
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped.